# how to override search_read() method in Odoo v.9?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

**Impacted versions: 9.0**

I am try to restrict some products based on category.

I have override *name_search()* method which work fine for *Many2one* field. But When I search product from search more option in *Many2one* field or search product from search menu in list view, it's show me that product.

I have tried following code:

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):

    _inherit = "product.template"

    def search_read(self, model, fields=False, offset=0, limit=False, domain=None, sort=None):

        res = super(ProductTemplate, self).search_read(model, fields=fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, domain=domain, sort=sort)

        return res
```

But it's give me following trace-back.

```
2016-07-29 05:09:01,167 9750 ERROR enterprise openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/http.py", line 680, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/http.py", line 316, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/http.py", line 959, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/http.py", line 509, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 847, in search_read
    return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 868, in do_search_read
    request.context)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/http.py", line 1064, in proxy
    result = meth(cr, request.uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo9/odoo-9.0e-20160127/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: search_read() takes at most 7 arguments (9 given)
```

**Question**:

1. How to restrict User to by-pass selecting product from search menu ?
2. How can I override *search_read()* method ?

Comment: What about overriding search() instead? search_read() is a combination of a search() and a read().

Comment: Hi @CZoellner I want to inherit the `Dataset's` controller like `call_button`, `search_read` etc I need your opinion on this like is it good to do so? Is it possible? is there any disadvantage of doing so.....because I want to call my APIs through these controllers instead of model's methods.

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors: do you want to migrate to later odoo versions -> probably making it more difficult to do so, do you have a good test suite to test those changes -> ok, should be always done, but this is a core feature so probably a lot of side effects. And some more, ofc, but if you have the time and motivation, why not? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
@api.model
def search_read(
        self, domain=None, fields=None, offset=0,
        limit=None, order=None):
    res = super(ProductTemplate, self).search_read(
        domain, fields, offset, limit, order)
    return res
```